# Permission denied error when installing "survHE" R package in Windows 11

Tags: r, permission-denied, survival-analysis

I always get the error message below when updating survHE via:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github('giabaio/survHE', ref='hmc', force = TRUE)
```

[....]

```
    Warning message:
In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\derek\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK\processx\libs\x64\processx.dll to C:\Users\derek\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\processx\libs\x64\processx.dll: Permission denied
```

The package developer isn't sure what's wrong and can't replicate as he doesn't use Windows. I have tried rebooting and running RStudio (or just R) as admin while installing. I need to do the update as I'm getting problems that the developer reckons may be due to bugs in the old version of the package.

Comment: Welcome to S.O.

I searched your error and found this... could it be about read/write permissions?
https://github.com/biocswirl-dev-team/BiocSwirl/issues/35

Comment: Thanks. It could be, but as I say I'm running it as admin and the processx folder lists admin and SYTEM, as well as my user name, under Properties>Security. Is there something else that I should be doing? @Michael

Comment: Ah! I have a guess. Note the package developer has specific instructions for installation on windows https://github.com/giabaio/survHE ```install.packages("survHE",
 repos=c("http://www.statistica.it/gianluca/R",
  "https://cran.rstudio.org",
                "https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/stable"),
 dependencies=TRUE
)```

Comment: Hmm, he told me to install this version: https://github.com/giabaio/survHE/tree/devel

I just install using your code above anyway but still get the same errors that I was trying to fix by updating/reinstalling. @Michael

Comment: @Michael - I tried to install the developer version using the instructions on the link you gave but just got loads of errors, e.g.

`> devtools::install_github("giabaio/survHE", ref="devel")
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘memoise’`

Comment: That kind of error is great (as in, clear message, probably an easy solution).... you just need to troubleshoot the installation of any packages that come up in the error messages. Try `install.packages("memoise")` and then follow the instructions on GH from the top again. If further errors of this sort, install the missing packages and try again. Good luck :-0